# 3D Texture Mapping in The Foundry Nuke

Tags: python, nuke

Here's a Nuke's Python script for creating a camera’s projection matrix and using paint strokes as a texture map. The idea behind it, is to project 3D texture of all objects in the Viewer to screen space through the currently selected camera using paint strokes.

Method `.getGeometry()` isn't working.

How to fix it?

[image]

Here's a code:

```
import nuke
import nukescripts

def paintPoints():

    geoNode = nuke.activeViewer().node()       
    camera = nuke.selectedNode()

    if not camera.Class() in ('Camera', 'Camera2'):
        nuke.message('Por favor, seleccione un nodo de la cámara primera')
        return

    geoKnob = geoNode['geo']
    objects = geoKnob.getGeometry()

    if not objects:
        nuke.message('No se han encontrado geometría en %s' % geoNode.name())

    pts = []

    for o in objects:    
        objTransform = o.transform()

        for p in o.points():    
            worldP = objTransform * nuke.math.Vector4(p.x, p.y, p.z, 1)
            pts.append([worldP.x, worldP.y, worldP.z])

    curvesKnob = nuke.createNode('RotoPaint')['curves']
    task  = nuke.ProgressTask('painting points')

    for i, pt in enumerate(pts):
        if task.isCancelled():
            break

        task.setMessage('painting point %s' % i)
        stroke = nuke.rotopaint.Stroke(curvesKnob)
        pos = nukescripts.snap3d.projectPoint(camera, pt)
        ctrlPoint = nuke.rotopaint.AnimControlPoint(pos)
        stroke.append(ctrlPoint)
        curvesKnob.rootLayer.append(stroke)
        task.setProgress(int(float(i)/len(pts)*100))

paintPoints()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since The Foundry engineers deprecated `geo` knob as well as its `.getGeometry()` method, we should use `.getGeometryNodes()` method instead.

If you need more detailed information about it [go here](https://www.mail-archive.com/nuke-python@support.thefoundry.co.uk/msg04521.html) and write your question.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you add custom knobs to nodes. More details and images in the [Nuke Developer Guide](https://www.thefoundry.co.uk/products/nuke/developers/100/pythondevguide/basics.html#adding-controls-to-nodes).

The following example adds a control to a blur node:

```
b = nuke.nodes.Blur()
k = nuke.Array_Knob("myctrl", "My Control")
b.addKnob(k)
```

`.Array_Knob` can be replaced with `.WH_Knob` for a slider or `.Boolean_Knob` for a checkbox.

Comment: I am a new developer to Nuke myself, so I don't know how you connect these custom knobs to influence the settings of the node. Will update when I know more.

Comment: Can you upload that nuke file for me to look at? Adjusting values of existing knobs is usually pretty easy. If you want a custom knob to adjust the value of other knobs, I believe you need to use expressions.

Comment: I've copied the script and I'm checking your code now. I've only done coding for nuke, so you'll have to tell me where the projected texture settings are. I didn't see anything in the settings for the camera or the rotopaint nodes.